# Float returning exponential notation

Tags: java, xpath

I'm writing a bit of code for use in an Xpath query which is causing a problem. I'm trying to read a random name from a list, however the float (x) occasionally returns exponential notation.

```
Random r = new Random();
float x = r.nextFloat();

final String expression = "(/list/name[@minLevel<=" + minLevel + "])" +
    "[(" + x + " * count(/list/name[@minLevel<=" + minLevel + "])) +1]";
```

Every once in a while, expression equals something like:

```
(/name/list[@minLevel<=11])[(5.478859E-4 * count(/name/list[@minLevel<=11])) +1]
```

And apparently xpath doesn't do math with exponential notation, because I get this error:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: 5.478859E-4 could not be formatted to a number!
```

Any help on how to prevent this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert the float, you could use [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) with [`%f`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) as the format specifier. This will never use scientific notation.

```
String.format("%f", x)
```

This also gives you the flexibility to tweak the width and precision as required.

Comment: %f could result in the number being rounded couldn't it?

Comment: @assylias Given the number is random, perhaps it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks much, I didn't even think of formatting. Sometimes it's the easiest things........

Comment: @assylias It is worth noting because this not typical. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of interpolating `x` directly into the string (`... + x + ..`), use this:

```
... + String.format("%f", x) + ...
```

You can also control the precision and width of the result using modifiers on the conversion. See the [formatting documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Answer (score 1):

Constructing XPath expressions by string concatenation is not usually the best approach. Quite apart from the risk of injection attacks, it means you lose the ability to compile the expression once and use it repeatedly with different parameters.

Instead, compile the expression

```
(/list/name[@minLevel<=$minLevel])[($x * count(/list/name[@minLevel<=$minLevel])) +1]
```

and then supply the values of parameters $x and $minLevel when executing it.